# Create class that implements a particular design pattern with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Design patters are a point of arguments between developers, but I use them very often. Even more, I use one of the most controversial of all common patterns - singleton.

Here is how I implement it in C#:

```
class MySingletonClass
{
    private static volatile MySingletonClass _instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    public static MySingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new MySingletonClass();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private MySingletonClass()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to be able to automatically create singleton classes while developing, with only entering a name for the class.

How can I implement this functionality with ReSharper? Can ReSharper pattern catalog be used for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Code Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) for it (a File Template if you wish every singleton in a new file).

There are instructions on how to create a template [from scratch](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Creating_a_Template.html) and [from existing code](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Creating_a_Live_Template_from_Source_Code.html) in the help files.